# Why is per app language not working with application context on pre Android 13

Tags: android, android-13

I am trying to implement the per app language feature that was introduced in Android 13. I am using AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales and it's working very well on Android 13. On Android 12 it's working if I use activity context but not application context. The following snippet from an activity produces different output on Android 12.

```
Log.d(TAG, applicationContext.getString(R.string.settings_change_button))
Log.d(TAG, getString(R.string.settings_change_button))
```

First line is printed in phone language and second in line is printed in app language. I added the AppLocalesMetadataHolderService as it is shown here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages#android12-impl

Should I do something else to get the application context to use the app language?

Comment: in history of Android base context would always return default locale of the system, so of course it will only work for Android 13+ (they modified something in the firmware) and for lower Android versions only for `AppCompat` activity because it uses modified context under the hood, so yeah with application context for lower Android versions it's only possible with using additional library compat method like `ContextCompat.getContextForLanguage(applicationContext)` as answered below

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately this seems to be the intended behavior which renders this feature to be useless for me. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243457462#comment2

Edit:
Fixed in https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core#1.11.0 if  you use ContextCompat.getContextForLanguage(applicationContext) instead of applicationContext directly. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat#getContextForLanguage(android.content.Context)

Comment: And they dont mention it in official docs ? ... thats why I wasted time on this ...

Comment: It has now been included in the official docs and support for non-Activity context has been added in the 1.7.0-alpha03 release https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#1.7.0-alpha03

Comment: running in the same issue. Is there any update?

Comment: Yes, using ContextCompat.getContextForLanguage(applicationContext) instead of applicationContext directly works fine for me. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat#getContextForLanguage(android.content.Context)

Comment: also it's better to use extension of course `val Context.languageContext: Context get() = ContextCompat.getContextForLanguage(this)` and then `context.languageContext.getString(R.sting.hello_world)`